# Is there a way to read the cache files from electron on linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron

I'm trying to make a function in my electron program that clears the cache file by file so I don't have to completely reload the cache every time I completely clear the cache, it works fine on Windows and macOS (because the cache files are just the file) but is very troublesome in Linux (I've found that there is both plain text and file data in the cache files) and I have not for the life of me figured out how to parse this data. Does electron have some API for this that I just don't know about? I'm really close to just giving up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The code responsible for checking cache on Windows and macOS is this: (note the code will be written to check the cache as if it was on Linux)

```js
//package refers to the package.json
//Reading Cache Files
fs.readdirSync(`${os.userInfo().homedir}/.config/${package.productName}/Cache`).forEach(e => {
    if (fs.lstatSync(`${os.userInfo().homedir}/.config/${package.productName}/Cache/${e}`).isDirectory()) return;
    var file = fs.readFileSync(`${os.userInfo().homedir}/.config/${package.productName}/Cache/${e}`);
    if (file === comparingFile) fs.unlinkSync(`${os.userInfo().homedir}/.config/${package.productName}/Cache/${e}`)
});
```

Comment: Might be helpful to see the relevant code...maybe you could edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after a few hours I was able to plow through andread more than half of the cached cached images. I just had to remove the request URL from the start and remove the http response from the end, and it works.